# Reducing flour coating on flatbreads

Tags: baking, flour, flatbread

Bit of a problem with flatbreads: the flour on them is excessive. I tried cornstarch and oats instead. I have 3 different brushes for getting the flour off them. For those wondering: it's sourdough starter+flour baked at around 550 degrees Fahrenheit. How can I avoid that much flour on the outside of the flatbread?

I roll the flatbread to the ideal consistency and about 1/4 to 1/8th of an inch thick, then dust with as much flour as I need. Then I quickly transfer it to a hot pizza stone.

Comment: Could you work with less flour on the bench? Can you elaborate a bit on your method and possibly recipe? You may always [edit] your post.